# Saving data during web session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

If I need to save a user’s data on which buttons they clicked while they visited our website, and without uploading a database would these be some of the ways? The problem is any array I have at that moment is reset everytime the user is redirected from the page.

Disclaimer: I’m new to PHP

1. **PHP class**. Create necessary push/pop features for an array and pass that class instance throughout the code. I tried this before but was having the issue of the array being reset no matter where I placed the code. Originally I had it on the header that is at the top of all pages but again this wasn’t the solution.
2. **Localstorags through JavaScript**. Haven’t used this yet as there has to be a better solution.
3. **Upload to database** Again, haven’t used this but there has to be a better solution as multiple MySQLi queries will surely be taxing.

Cheers!

Comment: sessions\cookies\file\db pick one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you don't want to use `localStorage.setItem('clicks', JSON.stringify(array));`
Depends on how big your array gets but should not be a problem for some clicks really.

Comment: But surely there’s another way than writing to client’s memory? Is there a way to have scripts run that are immune to being refreshed during the session?